# Blocking drop table for specific schema using trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to prevent anyone from dropping tables on a specific schema "public" unless the user is an `rds_superuser` but the function I wrote is guarding on all schemas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION guard_tables()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
IF TG_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_roles WHERE pg_has_role(CURRENT_USER, oid, 'member') AND rolname = 'rds_superuser') = 0 THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'command % is disabled for this table', tg_tag;
END IF;
END;
$$;
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` is not set in event triggers.

You'll have to call [`pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html#PG-EVENT-TRIGGER-SQL-DROP-FUNCTIONS) to get information about the dropped objects. Among the result columns is `schema_name`, which contains the schema name of the affected object.

Comment: Replacing that schema check part of the condition with this fixed it. Thanks! `SELECT schema_name FROM pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects() LIMIT 1) = 'public'`